# Hide <div class="kk-star-ratings top-right rgt" data-id="18">

Tags: css

Hi I can hide the element :  in all our site but I want to hide just on certains page. Which CSS code I can use as to hide only certains data-id :

```
<div class="kk-star-ratings  top-right rgt" data-id="18">
<div class="kk-star-ratings  top-right rgt" data-id="9036">
```

Comment: On all site this css work : .kk-star-ratings {
  visibility :hiden;}

Comment: But how hide only certains data.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you CSS, using [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) you could :

```
[data-id="18"] {
  /* styles */
}
```

With a class try this:

```
.kk-star-ratings[data-id="18"] {
   /* styles */
}
```

> Notice, there is no space between `ratings[data`

Comment: When I put : .kk-star-ratings [data-id="9036"] {visibility :hiden;} don't work ?

Comment: Try **removing space** between `ratings [`. It should be `.kk-star-ratings[data-id="18"]`. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> **[attr=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is exactly "value".

and hide like this:

```css
[data-id="18"], [data-id="9036"]  {
   display:none
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
[data-id="18"],
[data-id="9036"] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="kk-star-ratings  top-right rgt" data-id="18">hide</div>
<div class="kk-star-ratings  top-right rgt" data-id="9036">hide</div>

<div class="kk-star-ratings  top-right rgt" data-id="11218">show</div>
<div class="kk-star-ratings  top-right rgt" data-id="98756036">show</div>
```

Comment: WORK PERFECT ! Thanks Dippas

Comment: Thanks to Nikhil Nanjappa. Solve without space. And Thanks to Dippas.

Comment: @hood - Thanks, you can mark my answer as it will help others too.